# In Sublime3 (Win) add a build system for environment in WSL

Tags: bash, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Sublime Text 3 running on Win10, and I have an Anaconda environment under Windows Subsystem for Linux. I want to set a build system in Sublime Text that executes with the python I have in the Anaconda environment.
I have set the following helper bash script `python.sh`:

```
export PATH="/mnt/d/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
source activate myenvironment
python -u $1 
echo "closing bash"
```

In Sublime Text I have the following for the build system:

```
{
    //"cmd": ["bash", "/mnt/d/temp/python.sh", "${file}"],
    // "cmd": ["bash", "/mnt/d/temp/python.sh", "${file/([A-Z]):.*/\\/mnt\\/\\l\\1/}${file/[A-Z]:\\\\|\\\\/\\/\//g}"],
    "shell_cmd": "bash /mnt/d/temp/python.sh  ${file/([A-Z]):.*/\\/mnt\\/\\l\\1/}${file/[A-Z]:\\\\|\\\\/\\/\//g}",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Executing with that build system produces the following error:

```
ENULrNULrNULoNULrNUL:NUL NUL0NULxNUL8NUL0NUL0NUL7NUL0NUL0NUL5NUL7NUL
NUL
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 4294967295]
[shell_cmd: bash /mnt/d/temp/python.sh  /mnt/d/temp/import.py]
[dir: D:\temp]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;...]
```

The error is the same if I use `cmd` with list of variables instead of `shell_cmd`. Executing the command `bash /mnt/d/temp/python.sh  /mnt/d/temp/import.py` in a CMD window works fine:

```
D:\temp>bash /mnt/d/temp/python.sh /mnt/d/temp/import.py
120
123
closing bash

D:\temp>
```

Please advise if this can be solved.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a WSL issue - [Not working from Sublime Text Build system #1046](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1046)

Comment: Also: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2